# advanced custom fields acf_form() 'uploader' => 'basic' not working full wp media uploader showing on front end

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I have a front end post submission form. I would like users to be able to add images to the content with out having access to the media library.
I understand that `'uploader' => 'basic'` should show only a basic uploader but it still shows the full media uploader.
here's what I'm working with.

```
<?php acf_form(array(
                'post_id'       => 'new_post',
                'new_post'      => array(
                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish'
                ),
                'submit_value'      => 'publish',
                'post_title' => true,
                'post_content' => true,

                'updated_message' => __("Your post has been submitted for approval", 'acf'),
                'uploader' => 'basic',
                'return'        => home_url('user'),
            )); ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of advanced custom fields are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

'post_content' => false,

see https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf_form-and-basic-uploader/